# I must modifiy my links on my menu if use url rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess

In my site I use .htaccess for url rewrite.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ index.php?op=$1&idric=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ index.php?op=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Now I would like to know if I have to edit the "original" links in my menu

```
<a href="index.php">HOME</a>
<a href="index.php?op=src">SEARCH</a>
<a href="index.php?op=dts">DETAILS</a>
```

NEW

```
<a href="/">HOME</a>
<a href="/src/">SEARCH</a>
<a href="/dts/">DETAILS</a>
```

Or you can replace automatically using a url redirect or something else?
Thanks

Comment: No HTML links you have to replace yourself. Rewrite rules cannot change your HTML source.

Answer (score 1):

You can not replace them. But you can redirect them to the friendly URL's when they click on them.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\?op=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ %1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ index.php?op=$1&idric=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ index.php?op=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: What are the links you are clicking on?

Comment: mysite/index.php or mysite/index.php?op=src

Comment: If I click on my link href="mysite.com/index.php?op=src" the url not change in mysite.com/src/